# Memory Consumption in iPad

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, crash

I have built a huge app with 50+ `viewControllers` using `UITableView` and `UIImageView`.

When I run the app on iPad through Xcode with developer profile to check the memory consumption, the app crashes showing "Memory Pressure" warning in Xcode. The problem is sometimes it crashes when it had consumed 250+ MB RAM but sometimes it crashes at Only 50 MB.

What could be the reason for this? Its an iPad 2 with 512 MB of RAM.

Comment: it's likely because you're loading massive image files and `UIImage` objects into little bitty UIImageViews without resizing the image objects.

Comment: You need to Profile your app using Instruments to see what is happening. This is not something that there is a simple answer for - you need to measure what is actually happening. Allocating space for graphics is _normally_ where memory disappears to in a hurry - in general 4 * the number of pixels in each image loaded equals the number of bytes reserved. The number of view controllers in your app is likely a red herring - you will find that some of them perform worse than others, and some of them will likely need to be rewritten to use memory more sensibly. Measure, measure, measure, then fix.

Comment: but is there an explanation for why the app is crashing when it consumed 250 MB or 50 MB ... cause at 250 MB is agreeable but crashing at 50 MB? It sounds fishy.